# Create a folder in FTP using the {curl} package in R

Tags: r, curl, ftp

I am trying to create a new folder on my ftp using the `{curl}` package

This is what I tried so far:

Set up a handle with a custom request

```
library(curl)

h <- curl::new_handle() |>
  curl::handle_setopt(customrequest = "MkDir",
                      username = "my_username",
                      password = "my_passowrd"
  )
```

The folder `test` needs to be created

```
curl::curl_fetch_memory(url = "ftp://my_ip_address/test/",
                     handle = h )
```

with the following error

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url = "ftp://my_ip_address/test/", handle = h) : 
  Failed initialization
```

I even tried the `customrequest = "ftp-create-dirs"` and `customrequest = "MKD"`

with the same error message

Any pointers to how , or even where to read more, it would be appreciated

Comment: So just to clarify, the folder "test" does not exist and you want to create it?

Comment: @MrFlick, Yes, the folder `test` needs to be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a folder using

```
library(curl)
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, 
  userpwd = "user:12345", 
  customrequest="MKD test"
);
req <- curl_fetch_memory("ftp://my_ip_address", handle=h)
```

The custom request has both the "MKD" command and the name of the folder you want to create. I get a response of

```
Error in curl_fetch_memory("ftp://127.0.0.1:5021", handle = h) : 
  RETR response: 257
```

Which really isn't an error. The status code "257" just means that the folder was created so it's safe to ignore that message.

Comment: Works like a charm!. Many thanks. Do you have any good resources on cUrl so I can  associate it with the {curl} API in R?